# Dual of the SDP relaxation in Yinyu Ye's paper

Tags: optimization, duality-theorems, semidefinite-programming, relaxations

I was stuck in computing the dual problem in a [paper](https://doi.org/10.1109/TASE.2006.877401) by Yinyu Ye which raises an SDP relaxation such that

$$ \min_{Z \in \mathcal{K}} \left\{ h(Z) := \sqrt{\sum_{(i, j) \in \mathcal{E}} \gamma_{ij}^2 (g_{ij}^T Z g_{ij} - d_{ij}^2)^2 } \right\} \quad \mathcal{K} = \left\{Z: Z = \begin{pmatrix} Y & X^T \\ X & I_d \end{pmatrix} \succeq 0 \right\} $$

The paper gives the dual problem in the form

$$ \max \left\{  \begin{aligned}
& \sum_{(i, j) \in \mathcal{E}} \lambda_{ij} d_{ij}^2 + \sum_{(i, j) \in \mathcal{I}} \lambda_{ij} \delta_{ij} : \\
&\sum_{(i, j) \in \mathcal{E}} \lambda_{ij} g_{ij} g_{ij}^T + \sum_{(i,j) \in \mathcal{I}} \lambda_{ij} \frac{e_ie_j^T + e_je_i^T}{2} \preceq 0,~|\lambda_{ij}| \leq \gamma_{ij}, \sum_{(i, j) \in \mathcal{E}} \frac{\lambda_{ij}^2}{\gamma_{ij}^2} \leq 1
\end{aligned}    \right\} $$

where index set $\mathcal{I}$ corresponds to the indices of block $I_d$ in $Z$. And $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta function. May I ask how to formulate the dual problem? The paper simply skips the intermediate steps and gives the dual.

Comment: I would formulate the SDP+SOCP, write the Langrangian and use the method of this chapter https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/duality.html#lagrangian-and-the-dual-problem which is guaranteed to work with some steadiness and patience.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Can you give a sketch of the computation? Thanks in advance.